# How do I get my program to record every victory in my game?

Tags: python, file-io, time, python-3.3

Here's the code for recording victory/defeat:

```
def guessingTime(answer):
    vdfile = open("victorydefeat.txt", "w")
    now = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    print("That's 20! Time to guess.\n")
    guess = input("Is it a(n): ")
    if guess.lower() == answer:
        print("You got it! Congratulations!")
        vdfile.write("Victory achieved on ")
        vdfile.write(now)
    else:
        print("Sorry, but the answer was", answer)
        vdfile.write("Defeated on ")
        vdfile.write(now)
    vdfile.close()
```

Thing is every time it records it just overwrites the first line of the text file. How do I get it to record every victory/defeat the user gets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thing is every time it records it just overwrites the first line of
>   the text file.

This is happening because when you open the file you gave mode "w". On write mode, when you start writing something in the file you start from the beginning, as a result the new text replaces the old one. You need to set append mode "a"

Here is an example:

```
f = open('myfile','a+')
f.write("a line\n")
f.write("a new line\n")
f.close()
```

We open the file in append mode,
write the first line and add a new line character , then write second line , finally we close the file

Comment: So like this: vdfile = open("victorydefeat.txt", "w+a")?

Comment: Scratch that comment. It works now, but how do I get it to start a new line after the value of "now" has been written? Otherwise it writes it all as one continuous line.

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example. I added new line character as well to change line. If my answer helped you please accept my answer by clicking the tick in the left side of my answer.